# Change behavior of select[multiple] for single-click changes without CMD/CTRL

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multiple-select, multipleselection

I'm trying to change the default behavior of a  so that single-clicks on its options change the selected state of those options.

In other words, I want to remove unintuitive requirement of holding shift / ctrl to make multiple selections.

I'm trying with jQuery:

```
jQuery('select[multiple] option').each(function() {

var $this = jQuery(this);

 if ($this.is(':selected')) {
   $this.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this.selected = 'false';
   });
 } else {
   $this.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this.selected = 'true';
   });
 }
});
```

but it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543862/selecting-multiple-from-an-html-select-element-without-using-ctrl-key#27056015)

You can't depend on "click" event, the behavior of "select" and its "option"s is a bit different, you have to use mouse-events to achieve your goal.

**EDIT 2021:**

Best way to deal with this is actually to use checkboxes `<input type="checkbox">`, because browsers (mobile+desktop) will natively handle for you that without you trying to hack around it with an ugly script.