# Selecting multiple from an html select element without using ctrl key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've come across various solutions to this issue on the net.

Basically, I find having to hold down ctrl a bit cheesy, and I want the select list to just select whatever I click on and add it to the currently selected items.

I've already got this code:

```
    $("select[multiple] option").mousedown(function () {
        var $self = $(this);            

        if ($self.attr("selected")) {                
            $self.removeAttr("selected", "");
        }
        else {
            $self.attr("selected", "selected");
        }

        return false;            
    });
```

Element:

```
    <select multiple id="WOStatusKey" name="WOStatusKey">                
        <option value="1">Created</option>
        <option value="2">In Process</option>
        <!-- etc. (about 20 of these) -->
    </select>
```

It works fine with one exception: any time something is selected/deselected that is not at the top of the list (where you have to scroll to see it) then it pops back up to the top after you select it.  I've played around with it a little bit but can't figure out anything to prevent this behavior.  Also, I've seen a couple other solutions to this problem, although nothing that either works or works well.

I only need this to work in Chrome.  Also, I am not interested in any alternative solutions to using a select list.

Thank you for any help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this so others could also experiment with your code?

Comment: What browser? Not seeing the problem in chrome

Comment: janaspage: on your link, scroll down and click on an option.  After selection, the select box will automatically reset the position to be at the very top (as if you scrolled all the way back up).                                                      aa333: http://jsfiddle.net/h5Sw2/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can save the [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) and set it at the end.

```
$("select").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var select = this;
    var scroll = select .scrollTop;

    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

    setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);

    $(select ).focus();
}).mousemove(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UziTech/cjjg68dr/114/

Comment: Thank you sir!  I never did find a solution.  This works great!

Comment: Finally a solution that works! btw, tested it on Safari/Opera/Chrome/FF, doesn't work for FF

Comment: This fiddle doesn't work in the latest Chrome; as the OP described, if you select, say #2, and then scroll down to #9, the select box will auto scroll to #2 again immediately after click.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to set the scrollTop inside a setTimeout so it will update it at the end of the event loop

Comment: IE considers the select element the target instead of the option element. As far as I know there is no way to do this in IE

Comment: It works fine for me in IE 11. Also, it is the only solution that fits for me in all browsers. + 1

Comment: If you have `onChange` handlers that `preventDefault()` is preventing from working, just add `$("#mySelect").trigger("change")`. You'll still get the Ctrl+click effect.

Comment: @Noumenon I like this idea, but where do you insert this `trigger("change")` part in the above code?

Comment: @user1837608 Right after `$(select).focus()`.

Comment: In chrome, if I click up/down buttons on the scrollbar, it is broken. As I unclick the up/down button, it scrolls 1 line then resets the scroll position to undo it.

Comment: To fix up/down scroll buttons, see Cassio Ludewig's answer.

Comment: @Tony Brix: I know this entry is kind of old but.. It is possible to get the correct option by using the click position, the scrollheight of the select and the amount of options.

Comment: @Lain I could see an issue if people have zoomed the page in or out. You would need an accurate measurement of the height of each option.

Comment: @Tony Brix: IE does not provide the height of options sadly. That is why you need scrollHeight of the select and the amount of options (scrollHeight / options.length = optionHeight). I tested it quickly in my project and it works fine on zoomed in/out pages. I do not know if it works in all possible cases, but it works for me in my project _so far_ :-)

Answer (score 8):

Tony's answer makes the select arrows buggy, as they work only if you hold the mouse down.

I've combined a few solutions into this, and it works fine at least in Chrome and FF:

```
// multiple select: selectable without Control
$('select[multiple] option').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        that = this,
        scroll = that.parentElement.scrollTop;

    e.preventDefault();
    $this.prop('selected', !$this.prop('selected'));

    setTimeout(function() {
        that.parentElement.scrollTop = scroll;
    }, 0);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: only answer that works on chrome mobile cause it targets the `option` element

Answer (score 7):

Here is a pure JS solution:

```
element.onmousedown= function(event) {
    //this == event.target
    event.preventDefault();
    var scroll_offset= this.parentElement.scrollTop;
    this.selected= !this.selected;
    this.parentElement.scrollTop= scroll_offset;
}
element.onmousemove= function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Look at the parent element(the select box) and record the vertical scroll offset before selecting/deselecting the option. Then reset it manually once you have performed the action.

The reasoning behind preventing default behavior for the `mousemove` event is because if you don't prevent it and you happen to click an option while moving the mouse, all options will become de-selected.

Comment: This works fine. A side effect is that other events may not fire. After adding this, I observed the following: (a) a disabled multiselect select field accepted the selection of options when clicking at an option. (b) An event that has been registered at 'input' did not fire any more.

Answer (score 2):

Short quick version

Created
        In Process

```js
// this is for specyfic id  -> $('#WOStatusKey').

//below for all multiple select
$('select[multiple]').mousedown(e=>{
e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="WOStatusKey" name="WOStatusKey">                
        <option value="1">Created</option>
        <option value="2">In Process</option>
        <option value="3">Bla bla bla</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Would be even better if it displayed a ☑️ when option is selected and a  when it's not

Comment: I made a version of this in vanilla js and with checkboxes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78177261/3374574

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that appears to work in Chrome FF and IE.  It's not terribly pretty because it flashes a little bit when clicking.

```
var vals = [];
$("select[multiple]").click(function(e){
        var scroll_offset= this.scrollTop;
      var newVals = $(this).val();
    if (newVals.length === 1) {
        var index = vals.indexOf(newVals[0])
        if (index > -1) {
        vals.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        vals.push(newVals[0])
      }
      $(this).val(vals);
      this.scrollTop = scroll_offset;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq8u2x6q/2)

Answer (score 1):

For a pure js solution in chrome set the event listener on "onmouseup" instead. The event that resets the scroll to the first element is fired on the mouse up.
So for example:

```
element.onmouseup = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var st = this.scrollTop;
    setTimeout(function () { element.scrollTop = st; }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me than the other suggestions, because it is vanilla JS and it behaves more similarly to the original still, for example allows quick selection of many items via the shift key.

```
element.onmousedown = function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) return;
    event.preventDefault();
    this.focus();
    var scroll = this.scrollTop;
    event.target.selected = !event.target.selected;
    this.scrollTop = scroll;
    // make sure that other listeners (like Vue) pick up on the change
    // even though we prevented the default.
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This version allows users to see a checked checkbox when the option is selected and an unchecked checkbox when the option is not selected on a desktop device. Mobile device already have checkboxes for select multiple.

[image: native implementation of select multiple with checkboxes]

```js
const init = function () {
// native mobile select has already checkboxes on both ios and android
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)) {
    return;
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('select[multiple][checkboxes] option').forEach(option => {
    if (option.selected) {
      option.textContent = '☑️ ' + option.textContent;
    } else {
      option.textContent = ' ' + option.textContent;
    }
  });

  document.querySelector('select[multiple][checkboxes]').addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const initialPosition = e.target.parentElement.scrollTop;
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'OPTION') return;
    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
    if (e.target.selected) {
      e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent.replace('', '☑️');
    } else if (!e.target.selected) {
      e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent.replace('☑️', '');
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.parentElement.scrollTop = initialPosition;
    }, 0);
    e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    return false;

  });
}

init();
```

```html
<select multiple checkboxes>
  <option value="1" selected>Todo</option>
  <option value="2">In Process</option>
  <option value="3">Done</option>
  <option value="4">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="5">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="6">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="7">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="8">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="9">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="10">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="11">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="12">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="13">Bla bla bla</option>
</select>

VS

<select multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>Todo</option>
  <option value="2">In Process</option>
  <option value="3">Done</option>
  <option value="4">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="5">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="6">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="7">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="8">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="9">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="10">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="11">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="12">Bla bla bla</option>
  <option value="13">Bla bla bla</option>
</select>
```