# Make the select think ctrl is pressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I'm makin a select with the multiple property enabled.

```
<select id="lst_prueba1" size="8" multiple>
    <option>Alderaan</option>
    <option>Corellia</option>
    <option>Endor</option>
    <option>Kashyyyk</option>
    <option>Mustafar</option>
    <option>Naboo</option>
    <option>Nar Shaddaa</option>
    <option>Tatooine</option>
    <option>Yavin</option>
</select>
```

But i want to select the options without the need of pressing the ctrl key.
Is there a way to fake the press using javascript or what could in the onchange event?

The answer provided here didn't work for me:
[How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

Comment: Why not use good, old-fashioned `<input type='checkbox'>`s?

Comment: I already tried the post abaddon666 mentions and it didnt work for me. As for roy's answer i honestly didn' thought about it so I will try it.

Comment: I know it's not tagged, but allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: Sure, anything is fine for me.

Comment: @BetunHerreraAlanis didn't Abaddon666's answer work because it was using jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24543862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'd suggest using checkboxes as mentioned in the comments, this should do the trick. Works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Might want to test more depending on your requirements.

```
<script>
    var selected = {};

    $("#lst_prueba1").click(function(e) {

        var options = this.options;
        var option;
        var value;

        value = $(this).val();

        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            option = options[i];

            if (option.value == value) {
                selected[value] = !selected[value];
            }

            option.selected = !!selected[option.value];
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So far it seems it works fine :)
i did tried the posts attached as duplicates but for some reason they didn't work at all.