# Getting JS Script to work with multiple select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found two threads which answer my question of what code to use. However I have been searching here and the rest of the internet for something to demonstrate how to get the script to run. I have almost no experience with JavaScript which is probably why I can't get this.

Threads:
[How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

[Selecting multiple from an html select element without using ctrl key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543862/selecting-multiple-from-an-html-select-element-without-using-ctrl-key#27056015)

The code that I wish to use is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var select = this;
        var scroll = select.scrollTop;

        e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

        setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);

        $(select).focus();
    });
    $('select').mousemove(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

However I have no idea on how to get it to work with a multiple select dropdown menu. The example drop down that I have been using to try and figure out how to get this to work is:

```
<form id="AddProductForm" name="AddProductForm" method="POST">
<select id = "practice" name="practice" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

I don't understand how to get the script to run so that when I click on one of the options I don't need to hold ctrl down to select multiple.

Any help will much appreciated. Thanks!!

EDIT:

I have been looking at the two links and I have a page with the code on it but when I run it I still have to hold ctrl to be able to select multiple options.

Comment: I don't get why it doesn't work then, cause I've been looking at those pages for a few hours now.

Comment: Updated the answer with your javascript code (remember, the javascript code must be **after** the select tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript code must be **AFTER** the select tag. Copy-paste next code in a HTML file and open it in your browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="practice" name="practice" multiple>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var select = this;
        var scroll = select.scrollTop;

        e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

        setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);

        $(select).focus();
    });
    $('select').mousemove(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just needed to see what it would look like and you seem to be the only one who was willing to do that.